# Accesing script scope variables from modules

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

We use IronPython in our open source project. I have problem accesing the variables added to the script scope like

```
private ScriptScope CreateScope(IDictionary<string, object> globals)
{
    globals.Add("starting", true);
    globals.Add("stopping", false);

    var scope = Engine.CreateScope(globals);
    scope.ImportModule("math");
    return scope;
}
```

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/FreePIE.Core/ScriptEngine/Python/PythonScriptEngine.cs#L267

I can use the globals from the main script, but any module that is loaded will fail. How can it be fixed?

update: Given this module *mymodule.py*

```
if starting: #starting is defined on the scope
   ...
```

From the main script executed using this code

```
void RunLoop(string script, ScriptScope scope)
{
    ExecuteSafe(() =>
    {
        var compiled = Engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(script).Compile();

        while (!stopRequested)
        {
            usedPlugins.ForEach(p => p.DoBeforeNextExecute());
            CatchThreadAbortedException(() => compiled.Execute(scope));
            scope.SetVariable("starting", false);
            threadTimingFactory.Get().Wait();
        }
        scope.SetVariable("stopping", true);
        CatchThreadAbortedException(() => compiled.Execute(scope));
    });
}
```

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/FreePIE.Core/ScriptEngine/Python/PythonScriptEngine.cs#L163

```
from mymodule import * #this will load the moduel and it fails with
```

[image]

edit: In response to @BendEg's answer

I tried this

```
scope.SetVariable("__import__", new Func<CodeContext, string, PythonDictionary, PythonDictionary, PythonTuple, object>(ResolveImport));
```

`ImportDelegate` is not defined so tried using a Func instead, the ResolveImport method never triggers and I get the same exception that the name is not defined

edit: I changed the scope creation to

```
var scope = Engine.GetBuiltinModule();
globals.ForEach(g => scope.SetVariable(g.Key, g.Value));
```

Now the import delegate triggers but it crashes on first line with `global name 'mouse' is not defined`, mouse is not used from the module. It seems its confused when I add my custom globals to the `BuiltinModule`

Comment: Could you please provide a more complete example (e.g. what is executed against that scope and how it fails)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not the right answer, as still doesn't allow to share variables defined in the main IronPhyton script with the imported modules, however is a step forward.

This approach allows to set variables at the Engine level rather then the script level and they will be available in every imported module.

```
engine = Python.CreateEngine();
engine.Runtime.Globals.SetVariable("test_global", "This is a test global variable.");
```

then, within any IronPhyton script is possible to access it using an import:

```
import test_global
print(test_global)
```

Unlike ScriptScope, which makes them directly available, those Global variables need to be imported.

**Original article**
https://ludovic.chabant.com/devblog/2009/12/24/exposing-global-variables-in-ironpython/

**Disclaimer**
*I added this answer as I've been struggling to find any material on this topic other then this SO Q&A, so I'm posting this possible workaround to help future troubled readers (like myself)*

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, importing some module will create a new scope. So when creating an instance of `PythonModule` via `from ... import ...` they has it's own scope. In this new scope, your public variables are not available. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Workaround:

You could create some static class, which holdes the values. Than you can be sure, you always have them. For example:

```
namespace someNS
{
    public static class SomeClass
    {
        public static bool Start { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And than in your IP-Code:

```
from someNS import SomeClass

# Now you can access the member
yourVal = SomeClass.Start
```

maybe this is some thing you can use. You event don't need to set it as variable in the scope.

**EDIT**

Maybe this is working for you. In the code i override module importing and try to set the global vars:

First thing you need is, give IronPython some delegate, for module importing:

```
# Scope should be your default scope
scope.SetVariable("__import__", new ImportDelegate(ResolveImport));
```

Then override the import function:

```
private object ResolveImport(CodeContext context, string moduleName, PythonDictionary globals, PythonDictionary locals, PythonTuple fromlist)
{
    // Do default import but set module
    var builtin = IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(context, moduleName, globals, locals, fromlist, 0);
    context.ModuleContext.Module.__setattr__(context, "some_global", "Hello World");
    return builtin;
}
```

**EDIT**

Definition of `ImportDelegate`

```
delegate object ImportDelegate(CodeContext context, string moduleName, PythonDictionary globals, PythonDictionary locals, PythonTuple fromlist);
```

Comment: Are there any workarounds for this? Because we really need to have our global static variables accessable from any code

Comment: Not a solid solution I am afraid. we have a plugin structure, each plugin is registered on the scope with a name so you can access it like mouse.deltaX or keyboard.getKey(Key.A)

Comment: How about using some static `DynamicObject`?

Comment: A little better, but you would still need it change the code of the script to mystaticobj.mouse.DeltaX which will require all my users to update their scripts. Funny thing is this used to work with older version of Iron python so something have changed.

Comment: If i remeber correctly, there was some thing with shared scopes. Maybe this help. One possible thing is, you wrapp the .net calls in some IronPython modules. So they only need to import the IP-modules and internally they call the c# member.

Comment: I think your static approuch maybe is best, then i could do freepie.mouse from the modules pretty ok tradeof. I will test and report back

Comment: But will it really work, if you do "from someNS import SomeClass" will this work from sub modules? I do not want my users to be forced to write the import

Comment: Yes, you need to import it every where you want to use it. So in every scope :)

Comment: :/ I understand why, but it's not very nice from my perspective and my users. I use python as a controller for my program. So its all about these global variables.

Comment: @Anders i have  much better solution for you, please wait 2 minutes :)

Comment: @Anders added some example. Maybe this is what you are looking for!

Comment: This looks interesting, will look at it this weekend, and report back! Thanks a million. You sound like a Iron Python pro, our project needs some help with using the python AST for some advanced pre-parsing, if you are interested ;)

Comment: Just trying to dig into the IronPython core, we use IronPython in our company, so just have a lot to do with it currently :)

Comment: A func should work as well, same thing, will try however

Comment: @Anders i've defined it on my own. Just try to use it, this works for me. You make take a look at: https://github.com/simplicbe/Simplic.Dlr/blob/master/src/Simplic.Dlr/IronPython/IronPythonLanguage.cs here i've used it. `InitializeResolver` is called directly after initializing the ScriptEngien.

Comment: No change, the delegate does not trigger. Here is how I create my scope https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/FreePIE.Core/ScriptEngine/Python/PythonScriptEngine.cs#L267

Comment: @Anders i try to make a full working example in the next days, would this be ok?

Comment: That would be super :D  Please see edit.  If you manage to fix it I can do a pull request so that you get credit at Github

Comment: @BendEg  in 2020 this issue is still an issue and this post looks like the only place where to find information, did you guys managed in the end ?